# Dynamically assign ng-bind in form

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, binding

I have JSON like with data like this, unfortunately I cannot fix the data which comes from third party

```
$scope.mydata = {
  "SOB0": "7",
  "SOB1": "70",
  "SOB2": "790",
  ...
  ...
  "wb0": "7",
  "wb1": "17",
  "wb2": "8",
  ...
}
```

The problem is  the data received in JSON is not always the same for, the number of attributes, which may be one or more for each type i.e one attr SOB0 or many SOB0, SOB1, SOB2..

In the form I want to bind this data to a input field based on the number of attributes in the JSON for example if I have only three of type "SOB"

```
{"SOB0": "7", "SOB1": "70","SOB2": "790"..}

input ng-model="mydata.SOB0" size=6 
input ng-model="mydata.SOB1" size=6 
input ng-model="mydata.SOB2" size=6
```

There seems no way to interpolate like  `ng-model="mydata.SOB+$index"` 
or call a function to dynamically bind on the fly based on JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would put all my value of inputs in a $scope dict like this

```
//inside angular controller
$scope.values = {};
```

in the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in Object.Keys(mydata)"> 
    <input ng-model="values[i]">
</div>
```

Object.keys(object) will return an array with all the keys of a given object, in this case, the variable 'i' will be your SOB keys so then all the inputs will be binded to a dynamic dict which will use their key to reference the value inputed

Comment: Thanks ! Used your solution to solve my problem!
https://plnkr.co/edit/bmbDTcFnnG7tfxRZf6Rt?p=preview

Comment: Im glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

You can check the link

https://plnkr.co/edit/ofd2UaDes4oaxxjj4PcU?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="a in states track by $index">
        <input type="text" value={{a}}>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But the two way bind does not seem to work.

Comment: Thats bcoz I did not add ng-model to the input element

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` notation in javascript for variable object property names

```
<input ng-model="mydata[ 'SOB' + $index ]">
```

To iterate `mydata`

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in mydata">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mydata[key]">
</div>
```